# Compare Checkbox and Input Values

Tags: jquery, checkbox, icheck

**Issue:**

I'm trying to compare a checkbox value to an input value in the same table row. I'm comparing them on keyup. When a user fills in a value in the textbox it compares that value to the value of the checkbox. If the values are equal, I want the checkbox to enter a checked state.

Interestingly, my code does this, but only on the first instance of the checkbox/input.  Note that I am using the icheck plugin, so I'm using some custom events. Any help in the right direction is appreciated.

**Please see the snippet below.**

```js
$(function() {
  var payFull = $('input[type="checkbox"].payfull');
  var payNow = $('input[type="text"].paynow');
  var payAmt = $('#amounttopay');

  // Recalc Function
  function reCalc() {
      var sum = 0;
      payNow.each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
      });
      if (!isNaN(sum) && sum.length !== 0) {
        payAmt.html('$' + sum.toFixed(2));
      } else {
        payAmt.html('$0.00');
      }
    }
    // When Pay in Full Checkbox is Checked fill in Pay This Time Field with Invoice Amount Due Value
  payFull.on('ifChecked', function(event) {
    var val = $(this).val().replace('$', '');
    var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val(val);
    price;
    reCalc;
  });

  // If Pay in Full Unchecked then remove value from respective Pay This Time Input
  //if (event.target.checked === true) { // Only bind the ifUnchecked event if the checkbox is checked
    payFull.on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
      var removePrice = $(this).closest('tr').find(payNow).val('');
      $(removePrice);
      $(reCalc);
    });
  //}

  // If Pay This Time changes recalculate total
  var payFullVal = payFull.val().replace('$', '');
  payNow.keyup(function(event) {
    //  If Checkbox and Input values DO NOT match
    if (payFullVal !== $(this).val()) {
      $(this).closest('tr').find(payFull).iCheck('uncheck');
    }
    //  If Checkbox and Input values DO match
    else if (payFullVal == $(this).val()) {
      $(this).closest('tr').find(payFull).iCheck('check');
    } else {}
    $(reCalc);
  });
});
```

```css
/* iCheck plugin Square skin, blue
----------------------------------- */

.icheckbox_square-blue,
.iradio_square-blue {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.1/skins/square/blue.png) no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue.hover {
  background-position: -24px 0;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue.checked {
  background-position: -48px 0;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue.disabled {
  background-position: -72px 0;
  cursor: default;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue.checked.disabled {
  background-position: -96px 0;
}
.iradio_square-blue {
  background-position: -120px 0;
}
.iradio_square-blue.hover {
  background-position: -144px 0;
}
.iradio_square-blue.checked {
  background-position: -168px 0;
}
.iradio_square-blue.disabled {
  background-position: -192px 0;
  cursor: default;
}
.iradio_square-blue.checked.disabled {
  background-position: -216px 0;
}
/* Retina support */

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
  .icheckbox_square-blue,
  .iradio_square-blue {
    background-image: url(blue@2x.png);
    -webkit-background-size: 240px 24px;
    background-size: 240px 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.1/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#datatable input[type=checkbox]').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      increaseArea: '10%' // optional
    });
  });
</script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center view">View</th>
      <th class="text-center">Invoice Date</th>
      <th class="text-center">Invoice #</th>
      <th class="text-center">PO #</th>
      <th class="text-center">Invoice Amount</th>
      <th class="text-center">Amount Due</th>
      <th class="text-center">Pay In Full</th>
      <th class="text-center">Pay This Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="foot">
      <th class="text-left">
        <h5 class="semibold text-uppercase nm ml5">Pay This Time</h5>
      </th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="text-right">
        <h3 class="semibold nm mr5" id="amounttopay">$0.00</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">
        <label>
          <input class="view-detail" data-contextual="selected" data-target="tr" data-toggle="selectrow" name="SPI_Inv_Select" type="checkbox" value="SPI_Inv_Num">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">SPI_Inv_Date</td>
      <td class="text-center"><a class="uline" href='#'>SPI_Inv_Num</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">SPI_Inv_PONum</td>
      <td class="text-right">SPI_Inv_Amt</td>
      <td class="text-right">SPI_Inv_DueAmt</td>
      <td class="text-center payinfull">
        <input class="payfull" name="SPI_InvPay_Select" type="checkbox" value="$109.92">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center paythistime">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input class="form-control paynow" data-parsley-error-message="Invalid Character" data-parsley-errors-container=".one" data-parsley-pattern="^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$" type="text">
        </div>
        <span class="one"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center view">
        <label>
          <input class="view-detail" data-contextual="selected" data-target="tr" data-toggle="selectrow" name="SPI_Inv_Select" type="checkbox" value="SPI_Inv_Num">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">SPI_Inv_Date</td>
      <td class="text-center"> <a class="uline" href='#'>SPI_Inv_Num</a>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">SPI_Inv_PONum</td>
      <td class="text-right">SPI_Inv_Amt</td>
      <td class="text-right">SPI_Inv_DueAmt</td>
      <td class="text-center payinfull">
        <input class="payfull" name="SPI_InvPay_Select" type="checkbox" value="$6.65">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center paythistime">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input class="form-control paynow" data-parsley-error-message="Invalid Character" data-parsley-errors-container=".two" data-parsley-pattern="^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$" type="text">
        </div>
        <span class="two"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't wanna be the code review guy, but: ```$(removePrice);``` and ```$(reCalc);``` does nothing.

Comment: Nor do `price;` and `reCalc;` You might want to have another read over this code. In any case, the answer to "why does my code do this" usually best found by using the debugger and stepping through, watching it run.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I forgot to remove a if statement. Try again, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you

```js
var payFull = $('input[type="checkbox"].payfull');
var payNow = $('input[type="text"].paynow');
var payAmt = $('#amounttopay');

payFull.on('ifChecked', function(event) {
  $(this).parents('tr').find('.paynow').val($(this).val());
  Calc();
});
payFull.on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
  if ($(this).parents('tr').find('.paynow').val() == $(this).val()) {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.paynow').val('')
    Calc();
  }
});
$('.paynow').keyup(function() {
  var $ThisCheck = $(this).parents('tr').find('.payfull')
  if ($(this).val() == $ThisCheck.val()) {
    $ThisCheck.iCheck('check');
  } else {
    $ThisCheck.iCheck('uncheck');
  }
  Calc();
})

function Calc() {
  var Sum = 0;
  $('.paynow').each(function(index, Obj) {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(value)) Sum += value
  })
  $('#amounttopay').text(Sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
/* iCheck plugin Square skin, blue
----------------------------------- */

.icheckbox_square-blue,
.iradio_square-blue {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.1/skins/square/blue.png) no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue.hover {
  background-position: -24px 0;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue.checked {
  background-position: -48px 0;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue.disabled {
  background-position: -72px 0;
  cursor: default;
}
.icheckbox_square-blue.checked.disabled {
  background-position: -96px 0;
}
.iradio_square-blue {
  background-position: -120px 0;
}
.iradio_square-blue.hover {
  background-position: -144px 0;
}
.iradio_square-blue.checked {
  background-position: -168px 0;
}
.iradio_square-blue.disabled {
  background-position: -192px 0;
  cursor: default;
}
.iradio_square-blue.checked.disabled {
  background-position: -216px 0;
}
/* Retina support */

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
  .icheckbox_square-blue,
  .iradio_square-blue {
    background-image: url(blue@2x.png);
    -webkit-background-size: 240px 24px;
    background-size: 240px 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iCheck/1.0.1/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#datatable input[type=checkbox]').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      increaseArea: '10%' // optional
    });
  });
</script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Pay In Full</th>
      <th class="text-center">Pay This Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="foot">
      <th></th>
      <th class="text-right">
        <h3 class="semibold nm mr5" id="amounttopay">$0.00</h3>

      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center payinfull">
        <input class="payfull" name="SPI_InvPay_Select" type="checkbox" value="109.92" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center paythistime">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

          <input class="form-control paynow" data-parsley-error-message="Invalid Character" data-parsley-errors-container=".one" data-parsley-pattern="^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$" type="text" />109.92
        </div> <span class="one"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center payinfull">
        <input class="payfull" name="SPI_InvPay_Select" type="checkbox" value="6.65" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center paythistime">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

          <input class="form-control paynow" data-parsley-error-message="Invalid Character" data-parsley-errors-container=".two" data-parsley-pattern="^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$" type="text" />6.65
        </div> <span class="two"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center payinfull">
        <input class="payfull" name="SPI_InvPay_Select" type="checkbox" value="16.65" />
      </td>
      <td class="text-center paythistime">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input class="form-control paynow" data-parsley-error-message="Invalid Character" data-parsley-errors-container=".two" data-parsley-pattern="^\d+(,\d{1,2})?$" type="text" />16.65
        </div> <span class="two"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, J Santosh. I accepted your answer. I do have a few questions, so I understand your modifications. 1) What is the idea behind using .parents() instead of .closest() in this situation? 2) Why do we not want to store some of the selectors in variables like I did in my original snippet? Thanks!

Comment: 1.`closest` is not working here .   2. You cant pre-define selectors because you have many rows, so every time, you have to find the checkbox and input[type=text] selectors. @dentalhero. Glad to help :)